# encrypt file line by line using openssl on UNIX

Tags: unix, encryption, openssl, sas, aes

I need to encrypt a file containing one CLIENT_ID by line.

When I use 
`openssl enc -k jesuislacle  -aes256 -base64 -e -in &_fidat/num_tie_dmp.csv -out &_fidat/decrypted_numtie.csv`, I encrypt the whole file.
But what I want is to encrypt line by line. i.e.

Original I have:

```
ABCDEC
FGHHIJ
KLMNOP
QRSTUV
```

What I want :

```
QHXrpv3ah0qEPBECCt1//PBKiugmWYMuE+WaA4r9Rgc#
nAca0Pb6bH1cQRfkO9wReY+X6dgl44BKE/nKSFBLM+o#
UjTJsoHoLAC0GeqqImxDXX9znUtd7dGm4VODZ+T7lvM#
dcU+H+jd9RZZqweDu1nnJDWMlKjxW2Hc+Q2uAW1tQfk#
```

For the moment, I launch this command X times for each ID.
But I can have, more than 10000 ID to encrypt. It takes few hours to have the results. It's too much.

What's the best way.
I'm on SAS 9.3, UNIX and I have to encrypt in AES 256 not MD5 (thank's to my DPO :-) )

Thanks for your help.
Jérome

Comment: Please share the code you are currently using to run your openssl command 10000 times and perhaps someone can suggest an improvement to it.

Comment: Bonus points for a [complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) based on your sample data.

Comment: @user667489 : The command line is the one which is on the topics. I create a file 10000 times with one ID to encrypt.

Comment: This is part of the question, so please share your attempt at that part as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
while read line; do 
  echo "$line" | openssl enc -k jesuislacle -aes256 -base64 -e; 
done <infile >outfile
```

It reads all lines of the file one by one and encrypts it with the specified key.